# Play sound and Alterate UIView layer while Animating with Keyframes

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uikit, avaudioplayer

I'm kind of stuck since yesterday on an animation.

I use **UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:** to accomplish a long animation (duration of 6 sec with multiple steps).

It's fantastic, with frames I'm able to simply put instruction, order them and calibrate the whole thing really easily.

But there is one problem I'm facing :

- I don't manage to play sound at a particular keyFrame. (Using AVFoundation and AVAudioPlayer)

And, second and as big as the first :

- How can I alterate the layer of a UIView? If I need a View to move, then bring it to front (**bringSubviewToFront** on it) then move it again, actually it just bring the view to front before my animation starts.

And here you go, I'm trying to find a solution, but I'm starting to think that you can't specify sound play or layer alteration in frames.

```
 [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:6.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear animations:^{

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.12 relativeDuration:0.02 animations:^{
        [[AudioManager sharedInstance] playSoundForUrl:draw3Url];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [(UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0] setCenter:refImgView.center];
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.15 relativeDuration:0.02 animations:^{
        [[AudioManager sharedInstance] playSoundForUrl:draw1Url];
        [(UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:1] setCenter:CGPointMake(((UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]).center.x -
                                                                            ((UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]).frame.size.width * 0.35,
                                                                            ((UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]).center.y)];
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.17 relativeDuration:0.02 animations:^{
        [[AudioManager sharedInstance] playSoundForUrl:revert];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:[imageArray objectAtIndex:1]];
        [(UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:1] setCenter:refImgView.center];
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.2 relativeDuration:0.02 animations:^{
        [[AudioManager sharedInstance] playSoundForUrl:draw];
        [(UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0] setCenter:CGPointMake(((UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]).center.x -
                                                                            ((UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]).frame.size.width * 0.35,
                                                                            ((UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]).center.y)];
    }];
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.22 relativeDuration:0.02 animations:^{
        [[AudioManager sharedInstance] playSoundForUrl:draw3Url];
        [self bringSubviewToFront:[imageArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [(UIImageView*)[imageArray objectAtIndex:0] setCenter:refImgView.center];
    }];
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    if (val)
        [_delegateButton finishIntro];

}];
```

I'm not sure it will help since my problem is more on a principle basis than on actually code, but here you go.

Comment: Please share the code what you have done so far.

Comment: Edited, but I don't see the goal of it since my problem is not with my code but with how it works in general.